# Cant Return Responce from Django View to Front end

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have Django view which is responsible return response value after the file is modified.but it didn't receive anything.

```
 import pyinotify
 from django.http import JsonResponse

 def get_all_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
   print('Started')
   print(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "statics", "input"))
   wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
   notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm)
   wm.add_watch("statics/input.txt", pyinotify.IN_MODIFY, onChange)
   notifier.loop()

   def onChange(ev): #this function will be executed when chnage detected
    f = open("statics/input.txt", "r")
    value = f.read()
    print('change detected')
    return JsonResponse({'foo': value})
```

what I want is when the file is modified get all data inside that file to a Django template without refreshing the view.i use ajax request to get data from the back end.i couldn't understand what is wrong here.

Comment: Could you correct the indentations? It is hard to tell what lines are inside which function.

Comment: @Ralf so sorry I corrected it.all these belongs to `get_all_data` function

Comment: I don't see the actual view returning anything at all.

Comment: @GauravDhameeja is this wrong `return JsonResponse({'foo': value})`

Comment: But the view is not returning that. Only the nested callback does.

Comment: can someone suggest me a way to return JsonResponse only after that on cnChnage Event trigged

Comment: As @DanielRoseman stated, it's not the view that's returning the JsonResponse, it's `onChange`, and since you only call `onChange` without returning the value from it, your view never actually returns anything.